# UIWebView error

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am developing one application.In that first page having one `UIWebView`.And i create a  property for that one.And i created a object for that class in another class and give the html data for that webview like as below.But it didn't show the data on `UIWebView`.Please tell me how to do that one.

```
ViewController *view=[[ViewController alloc]init];
 NSString *result1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *htmldata=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@</html>",result1];
[view.web loadHTMLString:htmldata baseURL:nil];
```

This result1 string contain html data without html tag.That' why iam adding that tags.

Comment: Did you add the web view on the current view to see it (try to set the background color to check it), does the string `result1` has any text (NSLog `htmldata` to check or make an `if` check)?

Comment: programatically i added the UIWebview.And result1 and htmldata have data.

Comment: I don't see how the subview gets created.  Try `NSLog(@"Web: %@", view.web);` just before you load the html.

Comment: It will display web:null

Comment: @user1498119 Then the `web` object was not initialized by `view`, have you overridden the `init` method to initialize the `view` properties ? As your `web` is `null`, call `[null something]` does nothing.

Comment: S.I overritten the init method to inivialize the view properties.Then how can i access that webview from another class.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you had called `pushViewController` or `popViewController` to present the view or added the view object's view as a subview of the current view. Then make sure that the webview is allocated, given a frame and added as a subview of `ViewController`. You did not used the method `initWithNibName:`, therefor, if the webview is created from xib, it will not take.